# Objective C Syntax Error

Tags: objective-c, c

printf("%f A ball with a radius of 14.5 inches.");

How do I correct this?  I am trying to write a print function(Still pretty green when it comes to C) I am not sure how to correct it.

Comment: `%f` means that there will be a floating-point value in the parameter list, following the format string.  You could do `printf("A ball with a radius of %f inches", 14.5);`.

Comment: printf typically isn't used in objective-C. Try NSLog instead, for example `NSLog( @"A ball with a radius of %f inches", 14.5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may or may not be receiving a compilation warning with this because you are calling printf, have a specifier in your format, but do not provide a value. "%f" expects for you to pass a float value to it. The following:

```
printf("A ball with radius of %f inches.", 14.5f);
```

should work, if that is what you are looking to do. If it is, you might need to augment the `%f` to adjust for precision (something like `"%.1f"`).

Otherwise if you actually want to print the %f outright try this:

```
printf("%%f A ball with a radius of 14.5 inches.");
```

Happy coding!

Comment: @user3408665 Please hit the accept button if this answer solves the question. That way it gets marked as solved and the poster of the answer gets +15 reps